# How count how many response.status_code in [<Response [300]>, <Response [404]>, ...?

Tags: python-3.x

how i can count how many response_code i have after generator ? Need total response_code, total response_code "200" and total response_code "403"

```
  .......rest of code.......

folders = []
for path in directory_to_find:
    folders.append(f'{site_link}{path}')

    lnk_folders = (grequests.head(url, timeout=3, stream=True, verify=False, allow_redirects=False) for url in folders)
status = []
for response in grequests.map(lnk_folders):
    status.append(response)
    if response != None:
        find_progress = find_progress + 1
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:     
            .......rest of code.......


  .......rest of code.......


print(status)

[<Response [300]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, 
<Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>,     
<Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>,         
<Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, 
<Response [404]>, <Response [300]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, 
<Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>]
```

I need like when i print

```
print(ok_found)
13

print(forbbiden)
62

print(rest_statcode)
45
```

Thanks so much , for explain me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `status` list and collect the status codes of interest as in below example:

```
from http import HTTPStatus
from requests import request

status = []

response = request(method="GET", url="http://www.google.com")
status.append(response)  # OK

response = request(method="POST", url="http://www.google.com")
status.append(response)  # METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED

print(status)

ok = []
method_not_allowed = []

for item in status:
    if item.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK.value:
        ok.append(item)
    elif item.status_code == HTTPStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.value:
        method_not_allowed.append(item)

print(f"Total requests: {len(status)}, status ok: {len(ok)}, method not allowed: {len(method_not_allowed)}")
```